# Mobile device detection and redircting on mobile device in DNN

Tags: mobile, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN site having version-06.01.05 (142). Whenever user hits any desktop site URL through Mobile device then it should redirect to mobile site page.

Please let me know how I can achieve this in DNN.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may find this tutorial to be helpful:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/532/view/details/redirecting-website-visitors-to-your-mobile-website-using-dotnetnuke

Comment: Thanks for providing this but i have tried this in DNN 6 and found that there is no option to choose Platform from the dropdown